# Delphi7 Font dialog outdated on Windows 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

- Left - dialog of Win7 of modern apps
- Right - dialog of Win7 of my Delphi7 app

How to make my dlg modern? (How to patch Delphi7)

[image: Font]

Comment: What's on the bottom-left of the new dialog that needs to be hidden?

Comment: only font styles which aren't needed here.

Comment: Modify dialogs.pas to remove the `CF_ENABLEHOOK` flag from the `TChooseFont` record. Note that the VCL will not be able to center the dialog any more.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - surely that should be an answer not a comment...?

Comment: @Chris - I was having a hard time finding a reference for the behavior. I did findd now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The offending part for the new dialog to be shown, for Windows 7 and later, is the callback. Here's a quote from "[Font Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646958(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Customizing_the_Font_Dialog_Box_for_Win7)":

> If you enable a hook procedure without creating a custom template, the
>   default ChooseFont template for earlier Windows versions will be
>   loaded.

You can eliminate the hook procedure by modifying a copy of "dialogs.pas" and putting it in your source folder for the current project.

```
function TFontDialog.Execute: Boolean;
  ...
//    Flags := Devices[FDevice] or (CF_INITTOLOGFONTSTRUCT or CF_ENABLEHOOK);
    Flags := Devices[FDevice] or CF_INITTOLOGFONTSTRUCT;
  ...
//    hWndOwner := Application.Handle;
    hWndOwner := GetActiveWindow;
  ...
```

The latter modification is for displaying the dialog in a reasonable place. Once the hook procedure is disabled, the VCL will not be able to center the dialog. You will also lose "Apply" button functionality and other events (OnShow/Close).

Comment: Or you could just use the `TFontDialog.Template` property to provide a template so the older one is not used by default.

Comment: @Remy - You still need to modify dialogs.pas to set 'HInstance'. In any case, it's a good option to preserve event support anyway. .. If only one can make it work, which I couldn't with some simple testing. Preview area not working, apply button is always visible...

Comment: True enough. Later versions of Delphi have a `TFontDialog.TemplateModule` property to assign the `hInstance`. And yes, `CD_ENABLEHOOK` is needed for the `OnApply` event to work. Not sure about the other events, though. They do not go through the hook procedure. In `TOpenDialog`/`TSaveDialog`, for instance, the hook is needed for subclassing the dialog window, and then the subclass drives most of the events. That is not the case in `TFontDialog`. But removing the hook does break the subclass that updates the `TFontDialog.Font.Color` and `TFontDialog.Font.Charset` properties.

Comment: @Remy - Thanks for noting color and charset. Two additional lines can be modified for that: `FFontColorModified := True;` `FFontCharsetModified := True;` That would cause assuming them to be always modified.

Comment: OnShow/Close is lost because `FontDialogHook` - not being called itself - cannot call `DialogHook` which replaces the window procedure in `WM_INITDIALOG` (after centering.the dialog).